# Skip 'display: none' DOM elements when using Jquery to move through the sequence

Tags: javascript

I am using zoomooz.js, a very dated package, to build a visualisation. (https://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/)

I am encountering an issue with my zoomContainer. My zoomContainer is powered by a user-selection of the images they'd like to see. From 15 images, users can select one-by-one what they'd like to see. The images not selected are then hidden using CSS.

What I am finding, is that using zoomButtons - despite the fact that these elements are hidden using CSS, zoomooz.js will still 'fly' over to that top left-hand corner, of dimensions 0x0, to that invisible object during the cycle. I don't want them included in the cycle.

I understand that a solution might be to use something like .remove() or .detach(), but when I do that - it doesn't like edgecases where the 'first' image in the html is not included in the parent div. It'll return 0 and not zoom.

Comment: My reputation :(

Comment: Please include some relevant source code showing your issue. Preferably a codeSandbox we can check out.

Comment: It's a bit broken :(